# Jquery to trigger HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically, I have slider which I would like to be triggered from menu too. I use following `HTML` :

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('.advanced-slider').advancedSlider().gotoSlide(1);  return false;"> one </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('.advanced-slider').advancedSlider().gotoSlide(2); return false;"> two </a> </li>
</ul>
```

What would be the appropriate Jquery code to trigger this?

Comment: Does what you have not work?

Comment: You're already using jQuery to do it.

Comment: Do you want remove the "onclick" of your links?

Comment: No, I wonder should I use some more Jqery function to activate this? Or bedides this I need to just include Jquery library and that's it?

Comment: May you post a jsfiddle with a working example of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just that:

```
<ul id="myul">

<li> <a href="#"> one </a>  
</li>
<li> <a href="#"> two </a>  
</li>

</ul>
```

```
$(function () {
  var $slider = $('.advanced-slider').advancedSlider();
  $("#myul a").each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $slider.gotoSlide(i)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think not. Live site is here http://sandagebell.biklopsdesign.com/ 

When you scroll down you will see menu on orange background, and slider below. 

What I am trying to achieve is that when someone presses link from the menu, the slider trigers and moves on directed slide. 

I wonder is it enough to just triger jquery in html(like <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('.advanced-slider').advancedSlider().gotoSlide(1);  return false;"> one </a>) , or I should write some more Jquery code? 

If I am right, Jquery is auto included in WP so I must not include it again.